# how to connect the spinner with my converter

Tags: java, android, spinner

1. **I need to connect the spinner with editText to get the result for converter**

   There is no connection between spinner and my converter.

   ```
   public class A01Acre extends Activity {
       Spinner spinnerarea;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.a01acre);  


           final    EditText editAcre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAcre);        
           final    EditText editHectar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHectar);        
           final    EditText editSquareinch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquareinch);
           final    EditText editSquarekm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquarekm);
           final    EditText editSquaremeter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquaremeter);
           final    EditText editSquaremile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquaremile);
           final    EditText editSquareyard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSquareyard);

           Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonConvertAcre);
           buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                   //try
                   try {
                       //    
                       double acre = Double.valueOf (editAcre.getText().toString());
                       double hectar = acre * 0.404686;
                       double squareinch = acre * 6.273e+6;
                       double squarekm = acre * 0.00404686;
                       double squaremeter = acre * 4046.86;
                       double squaremile = acre * 0.0015625;
                       double squareyard = acre * 4840;


                       editHectar.setText (String.valueOf(hectar));
                       editSquareinch.setText (String.valueOf(squareinch));
                       editSquarekm.setText (String.valueOf(squarekm));                    
                       editSquaremeter.setText (String.valueOf(squaremeter));
                       editSquaremile.setText (String.valueOf(squaremile));                    
                       editSquareyard.setText (String.valueOf(squareyard));        

                       //catch
                   } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                       // write a message to users
                       editHectar.setText ("");
                   }
               }


           });


           spinnerarea = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerarea);

           ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                   this, R.array.spinnerTestArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           spinnerarea.setAdapter(adapter);
           spinnerarea.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectdListerne());
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy(){
           super.onDestroy();
       }


       public class MyOnItemSelectdListerne implements OnItemSelectedListener {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> patent,
                   View view, int pos, long id) {
               String str = patent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().toUpperCase();
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {




           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: if possible be some precise.. What do u want to display onto the spinner?

Comment: This is some really clean code, so props for that. I'm not sure I understand the question though..

Comment: in the spinner there is Acre and hectare and so on!! i would like when i am changing the Acre to hectare get the hectare result

Answer (score 1):

Add a switch statement to your `onItemSelected()` method - switching on `pos`.

For each unit (each `case`), you can recalculate and then output the value to the user.

Something like,

```
switch(pos) {
    case 0:
        //acre - redo calculation
        break;
    case 1:
        //hectare - redo calculation
        break;
    case 2:
        //squareinch - redo calculation
        break;
    //...
    default:
        throw new UnexpectedException();
}

//display results to user
```